# JavaFX make imageView go in direction it is facing

Tags: java, javafx, imageview

I want to make an imageView object move into the direction it is facing.

I made it move on X/Y axis and also made it rotate but I literally do not know how to approach this issue of moving into the direction it is facing (for example, in my code I use a car, I just want it to move in the direction its facing)

I appreciate any ideas or tutorials where I could learn this.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private static final double W = 800;
    private static final double H = 600;
    private boolean goNorth, goSouth, goWest, goEast;
    private ImageView hero;
    private int toAngle = 0;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileInputStream hero_image_input = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\A650262\\Desktop\\police-310208_1280.png");
        Image hero_image = new Image(hero_image_input);
        hero = new ImageView(hero_image);

        hero.setFitHeight(120);
        hero.setFitWidth(200);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,800);

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){ 
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event)
            {
                switch(event.getCode())
                {
                case UP: goNorth = true; break;
                case DOWN: goSouth = true; break;
                case LEFT: goWest = true; break;
                case RIGHT: goEast = true; break;
                }
            }
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event)
            {
                switch(event.getCode())
                {
                case UP: goNorth = false; break;
                case DOWN: goSouth = false; break;
                case LEFT: goWest = false; break;
                case RIGHT: goEast = false; break;
                }
            }
        });


        root.getChildren().addAll(hero);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                int dx = 0, dy = 0;

                if (goNorth) dy -= 5;
                if (goSouth) dy += 5;
                if (goEast) rotate(3);
                if (goWest)  rotate(-3);

                moveHeroBy(dx, dy);
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private void moveHeroBy(int dx, int dy) {
        if (dx == 0 && dy == 0) return;
        double x = dx + hero.getLayoutX();
        double y = dy + hero.getLayoutY();
        moveHeroTo(x,y);

    }

    private void moveHeroTo(double x, double y) {
        hero.relocate(x, y);
        System.out.println(hero.getNodeOrientation() + " " + hero.getEffectiveNodeOrientation());

    }

    public void rotate(int angle){

        toAngle = toAngle + angle;
        if (toAngle == 360)
        {
            toAngle = 0;
        }
        hero.setRotate(toAngle);
    }


}
```

Comment: As a general idea, the direction the `ImageView` is "facing" and the direction of the movement should be ascertained from the same piece of information - meaning that the direction it's facing shouldn't be considered when trying to determine the direction of movement, because both decisions are made from the same piece of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Rotate` and `Translate` transforms to move the image. This way you can use the `Rotate` to transform the direction the car initially faces to the current one.

```
private final Rotate rotate = new Rotate();
private final Translate translate = new Translate();

// upwards facing direction TODO: adjust
private final Point2D initialDirection = new Point2D(0, -1);
```

```
rotate.setPivotX(hero.getFitWidth() / 2);
rotate.setPivotY(hero.getFitHeight() / 2);
hero.getTransforms().addAll(translate, rotate);
```

```
AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
    @Override
    public void handle(long now) {
        double delta = 0;

        if (goNorth) {
            delta += 5;
        }
        if (goSouth) {
            delta -= 5;
        }
        if (goEast) {
            rotate(3);
        }
        if (goWest) {
            rotate(-3);
        }

        Point2D pt = rotate.deltaTransform(initialDirection.multiply(delta));

        moveHeroBy(pt.getX(), pt.getY());
    }
};
```

```
private void moveHeroBy(double dx, double dy) {
    if (dx == 0 && dy == 0) {
        return;
    }
    double x = dx + translate.getX();
    double y = dy + translate.getY();
    translate.setX(x);
    translate.setY(y);
}

public void rotate(int angle) {
    angle += rotate.getAngle();
    if (angle == 360) {
        angle = 0;
    }
    rotate.setAngle(angle);
}
```

Comment: Hi and thank you very much. Indeed, it is exactly what I was looking for. However, could you please explain to me what the Point2D pt code line is actually doing?

Comment: `initialDirection` is the direction the car is facing (length 1). After multiplying with `5` or `-5` it is 5 times as long and in the latter case the direction is reversed. `rotate.deltaTransform` applies the rotation without applying any translations the transformation would usually do since the relative movement is used. `hero.getTransforms().addAll(translate, rotate);` results in the rotation being applied first (for the image to face the right direction) and after that the translation (for the image to be placed at the right position).